# How to add likes in linkedIn using API in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

This is POST method using VB.NET pls help where i have error. Am getting 400 error that is "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request"..... My method is below....

```
Public Function Linked_DataApi_Call(ByVal RequestUrl As String) As String
    Try
        Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(RequestUrl)
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials               
        request.Method = "PUT"
        /*Here am getting error:"The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request"*/

        Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse
        Console.WriteLine(CType(response, HttpWebResponse).StatusDescription)
        Dim dataStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream
        Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
        Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd
        Return responseFromServer

    Catch ex As Exception
        Return ex.Message
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: your heading says `POST` method but you are using `request.Method = "PUT"`. Which is it?